# basic authentication does not work for local testing with cypress

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, windows-authentication, basic-authentication, cypress

I am developing a web app that requires windows credential. To test it locally during developing, I decide to try cypress.io. However, I cannot make it work. I always got an 401-unauthorized error. Here are some codes that I have used for my testing. Thanks for your help.

method 1:

```
describe('My First Test', function() {
     it('Visits the Kitchen Sink', function() {
         cy.visit('http://localhost:8080/')
     })
})
```

method 2:

```
describe('My First Test', function() {
    it('test website loading', function() {
      cy.visit('http://localhost:8080/',{
        auth: {
          username:'myusername',
          password:'myassword'
        }
      })
    })
  })
```

method 3: overwrite command

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (orig, url, options) => {
    options = options || {}
    options.auth = {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
    }
    return orig(url, options)
})
```

Comment: There's an open issue that appears to be on [basic auth](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/908). While you wait for that you could try running [cntlm](https://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=cntlm) with basic auth.

Comment: Thanks for your info, lloyd.